# How to combine multiple condition

Tags: mysql, postgresql, if-statement, group-by, case

Dears

im trying to modify below queries to have this result as the table attached , if someone can help me

- i need to use case statement or if statement i think

[image: query]

[image]

thanks in advance,

Comment: please add your content as text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question  and also include the original data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select date(created_utc),
  count(case when isMnp = 0 and isEsim = 0 then 1 end) SIM,
  count(case when isMnp = 1 and isEsim = 0 then 1 end) MNP,
  count(case when isMnp = 0 and isEsim = 1 then 1 end) eSIM,
  count(case when isMnp = 1 and isEsim = 1 then 1 end) "eSIM-MNP"
from "Order" 
where status = 'completed' and date(created_utc) >= '2020-04-25'
group by date(created_utc)
```

If the columns `isMnp` and `isEsim` are `boolean` then use this:

```
select date(created_utc),
  count(case when not isMnp and isEsim then 1 end) SIM,
  count(case when isMnp and not isEsim then 1 end) MNP,
  count(case when not isMnp and isEsim then 1 end) eSIM,
  count(case when isMnp and isEsim then 1 end) "eSIM-MNP"
from "Order" 
where status = 'completed' and date(created_utc) >= '2020-04-25'
group by date(created_utc)
```

Comment: Many thanks i really appreciate your help but when i tried to run it i faced this error SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 58

Comment: Which column is boolean?

Comment: Check my 2nd query.

Comment: I add single quotation to the 0 and 1 in column isMnp and isEsim and its worked.

Comment: but how about if i want the date interval is the previous 4 days from now ?

Comment: `where date(created_utc) >= current_date - interval '4 day'`